# Pretty Url Angularjs not found patch

Tags: angularjs

I try remove # in url . It's working fine before i remove it . But when i remove , I get err in console cant get file patch . Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
      <base href="/">

    </head>
    <body>
                <a ui-sref="main">Main</a>
                <a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
<div ui-view>


        <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="testroute.js"></script>
    <script src="testservices.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is js config

```
function configRoute($stateProvider,$locationProvider){
             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

                $stateProvider
                    .state('main',{
                        url:'/main',
                        templateUrl:'test2.html',
                        controller: 'myController',
                        controllerAs:'vm'
                    })
                    .state('login',{
                        url:'/login',
                        templateUrl:'test1.html',
                        controller:'testController',
                        controllerAs:'vm'
                    })
```

Here is err i get

```
GET http://localhost:8080/test.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8080/testroute.js 
GET http://localhost:8080/testservices.js
```

Comment: Which build system you are using? Grunt, Gulp or webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Try to give solution folder name in base tag as example below,

```
<base href="/SolutionFolder/">
```